# django raise other status code than http404?

Tags: django, http-response-codes

I'm new to both web in general/django world. I've been raising `Http404` for all my error cases (from my view). I think raising other than `404`, such as `401, 402..` for different errors would be much nicer for me to detect what's gone wrong.

I found `return HttpResponse(status=401)` would do the job. But is this considered an acceptable practice? Should I not interfere with status code because each of them is supposed to mean something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the status codes has a specific meaning. See the [List of HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) page on Wikipedia page for the meaning of each code.

You should choose an appropriate status code for each response. For example, you should only use `401` when the client is unauthorized. It's not a great idea to assign your own meanings to the status codes.

If you want to make it easier to detect the error, you could [set a custom header](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#setting-headers) instead:

```
response = HttpResponse()
response['My-App-Error'] = error_code
return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can subclass `HttpResponse` to handle different types of HTTP responses.
More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#ref-httpresponse-subclasses)

For example, you can send `HttpResponse` with `status code 403` as:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest

def my_view(request):
    # ...


    return HttpResponseBadRequest('<h1>You are not authorized to view this page</h1>')
```